# How do I parse large .xls files in an ElectronJS app in the background?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying a basic ElectronJS app, wherein I am trying to read an .xls file from the local filesystem and try to parse it:

```
const electron = require('electron')) 
const dialog = electron.remote.dialog 
const fs = require('fs') 
const $ = require('jquery') 
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx')s[0])

$('#button').on('click', function(){
    dialog.showOpenDialog((fileNames) => {
        var obj = xlsx.parse(fileNames[0])
        $.each(obj[0].data, function(a,v){
          console.log(v[1])
        })   
    }) 
})
```

The file has around 300,000 rows and the code is able to parse and enlist data from all the rows. However, till the time it parses the file, the application GUI becomes unresponsive. How can I make this code run in the background to not have this issue?

Comment: use webworkers or use a hidden browser window